# After submitting form, the value is different due to encoding? (Python)

Tags: python, django

I am using Django.

In a regular form, the user enters "Gerry & Pacemakers".

(Notice the Ampersand sign.)

When I go views.py...

```
def myview(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q','').strip()
    print q
```

q is "Gerry"...but it's supposed to be "Gerry & Pacemakers"...encoded
Is the correct way doing this by using urllib??

How do I encode it BEFORE it hits the view?
It's very weird, because the URL contains the encoding:
?q=gerry+%26+pacemakers

Comment: Alex, you don't have to stick (python) in the subject. It's tagged as python, that's enough. IMO. (Not that it hurts or anything, I just thing it looks funny).

Comment: "How do I encode it BEFORE it hits the view?"

That's the browsers job. The problem seems rather that it gets decoded in the wrong place or once too much... Don't know Django enough to help you though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are pulling the data from request.GET, it looks like you're building the URL in the browser somehow.  You need to use the Javascript `escape()` function to handle URL-significant characters properly.

Comment: `escape()` function do different thing in different browsers, so it would be better to use `encodeURIComponent()`.

Comment: Actually escape is consistent over browsers... it's just consistently wrong. :-) encodeURIComponent is indeed the correct function for building query strings.